# A Good design in Swift for a model that has many aspects?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

I would like to ask a question about a good example of how to define a model with many aspects in swift, especially when the project gets bigger and bigger and one model has many aspects. The questions is pretty long but I just would like to know how ppl design a model in a big project. Any comments or thought would be appreciated.

Let's say there is a model called "Book" and it is defined like below:

```
class Book {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var author: String
    init?(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        // parse the model from JSON
    }
}
```

`Book` has a failable initialiser that parses properties from JSON sent from the server. 
On view controller A, it describes the more detailed information about the mode Book, so some properties are added to the model when it is used on view controller r A:

```
class Book {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var author: String

    // required on View Controller A
    var price: Int
    var seriersName: String
    var reviewNumber: Int
    var detailedDescription: String

    init?(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        // parse the model from JSON
    }
}
```

On another view controller B, we want to show the history of book purchase. So the model needs additional properties as below:

```
class Book {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var author: String

    // required on View Controller A
    var price: Int
    var seriersName: String
    var reviewNumber: Int
    var detailedDescription: String

    // required on View Controller B (Not required on VC A)
    var purchasedDate: NSDate
    var expireDate: NSDate

    init?(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        // parse the model from JSON
    }
}
```

This definition of Book lacks flexibility because the JSON passed to the failabel initialiser must have all of the properties even on an VC that uses only some of the properties.

**Solution A:**
I think the simplest solution for this is just declaring those additional properties as optional, but I personally think this is not so cool because whenever those optional properties are used they need to be checked if they are not nil.

```
if let seriesName = book.seriesName {
    self.seriesNameLable.title = seriesName
}
```

This kind of optional binding code will be overflowed all over the codes I assume. Implicit optional binding might be able to used but that is not really safe to use.

**Solution B:**
Another solution might be to define different models that inherits Book, like BookA and BookB. But what if we need a model that has BookA and BookB's aspects at the same time?

I guess there is no single solution for this kind of problem but I would like to know how other ppl define a model in a big project. (I wonder if someone would have a cool solution using some "swift specific" features like protocol and its extension :). I would appreciate any kind of opinions... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm not a Swift programmer, this are extrapolations I make from other languages with the same features and my Swift syntax might not be 100% accurate*

Using [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) I would do something like:

```
class EBook: Book, HasOnlineSource {
  ...
} 

class OtherKindOfBook: Book, WithCollectorEditions, HasBleh, WithFoo {...}
```

But you must ask yourself:

#### Do I need this to change dinamically?

If that is the case, you would need to go with Delegation through composition.

#### Are different parts of the application using the core models differently?

Or in other words, are there different users of those models needing different behavior? In that case, extensions are very useful since allow to expose different behaviors for the same model depending on their context. For instance, the Reporting module can send the message `numberOfReaders` while the Selling module could ask for `promotionalCodes`. Both are using the same model, but interacting with different protocols. In your case, you have different controllers wanting different things, so this might apply.

#### Using delegates

This follows the **Composition over inheritance** principle, but after reviewing how [delegates work in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html), I understood that they are not a native implementation but still a design pattern (a feature request you might say), the delegation is being made by hand.

Other languages allow you to make a `JSSONSerializableBook` with a `BookProtocol`, but instead of implementing what is required on `BookProtocol` you can set a delegate upon initialization which will implement such protocol. This delegate will be an internal collaborator of  `JSSONSerializableBook` and all messages that are part of `BookProtocol` received by `JSSONSerializableBook` will be delegated to it. 
Or in other words, the message passing is handled automatically (here is the [Kotlin documentatin on delegates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) if you want to check how other language implements it).

If you want to do the same on Swift, you must explicitly make the message passing to your delegate. 
This design has several advantages but since there is no native support for message passing it becomes very verbose to implement.

For further reference you can check the papers on [mixins](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3xZ6L0-LKAhVKFJAKHQ3KCEEQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbracha.org%2Foopsla90.ps&usg=AFQjCNEAPSmMK0QXNbqJgiasS-thS9CHBw&sig2=km0mbfjI_doQs8zmdDW0sQ) and [traits](http://www.ptidej.net/courses/ift6251/fall06/presentations/061122/061122.doc.pdf) to have some insight on the design decisions  behind this features.

Comment: Declaring protocols and defining separate classes sounds like a cool idea... Maybe a function to parse the JSON can be declared as protocol extension. And thanks for those references. I am excited to read them. By the way, would you be able to elaborate a bit further about the other approach, "delegating to the core book and wrapping it" in any chance? I'm quite intrigued but sounds like a completely new approach for me...

Answer (score 0):

This is why Swift has optionals.

If not all `Books` have, say, a `purchasedDate` then that should be an optional and then your initialiser doesn't need to fail if that field isn't present in the JSON.

It is your view controllers that will enforce the business logic - so if `ViewControllerB` gets a `Book` without a `purchasedDate` it should generate some sort of error.

It also may be that your base class needs to be decomposed into smaller objects.

For example, you could probably have a PurchaseEvent that is associated with a Book rather than storing that data in the Book itself.

Think of the characteristics of a book in the real world; it has the basic properties you first listed and may even have a price (on the back cover) but it doesn't tell you when it was sold and for how much.

However, @Logain's idea of using Protocols is also good, although it may be tricky when it comes to keeping the server JSON side in sync with the app code.

Comment: I agree with you. But my question is more like what would you do when the project gets bigger and the base model class gains lots of properties. More specifically, in my project, the base class which is defined in objective-c has like 50 properties right now and I just realised that i need to declare most of them as optional when I re-write the code in Swift. That is not really convenient because most of the properties need optional binding whenever they are used and it will make the code really long...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have a view controller responsible for presenting “more detailed information” about a book, then let's call it `BookDetailsViewController`, instead of the meaningless “View Controller A”. Similarly we should talk about `BookHistoryViewController`, not “View Controller B”.

If you want to treat the “more detailed information” as all-or-nothing, then encapsulate it as such, in a `Details` object that the `Book` object optionally reference. Same with the history. So here's a model:

```
class Book {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let author: String

    // These can't be lets because each requires self to initialize.
    private(set) var details: Details?
    private(set) var history: History?

    init?(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        guard let
            id = json["id"] as? String,
            title = json["title"] as? String,
            author = json["author"] as? String
        else {
            // These assignments will be unnecessary in the next version of Swift.
            self.id = ""
            self.title = ""
            self.author = ""
            return nil
        }
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.details = Details(book: self, json: json)
        self.history = History(book: self, json: json)
    }

    class Details {
        unowned let book: Book

        let price: Int
        let seriesName: String
        let reviewNumber: Int
        let detailedDescription: String

        init?(book: Book, json: [String: AnyObject]) {
            self.book = book
            guard let
                price = json["price"] as? Int,
                seriesName = json["seriesName"] as? String,
                reviewNumber = json["reviewNumber"] as? Int,
                detailedDescription = json["detailedDescription"] as? String
            else {
                // These assignments will be unnecessary in the next version of Swift.
                self.price = 0
                self.seriesName = ""
                self.reviewNumber = 0
                self.detailedDescription = ""
                return nil
            }
            self.price = price
            self.seriesName = seriesName
            self.reviewNumber = reviewNumber
            self.detailedDescription = detailedDescription
        }
    }

    class History {
        unowned let book: Book

        let purchasedDate: NSDate
        let expireDate: NSDate

        init?(book: Book, json: [String: AnyObject]) {
            self.book = book
            guard let
                purchasedDate = (json["purchasedDate"] as? Double).map({ NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: $0) }),
                expireDate = (json["expireDate"] as? Double).map({ NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: $0) })
            else {
                // These assignments will be unnecessary in the next version of Swift.
                self.purchasedDate = NSDate()
                self.expireDate = NSDate()
                return nil
            }
            self.purchasedDate = purchasedDate
            self.expireDate = expireDate
        }
    }
}
```

Given this model, you can allow the user to ask for a `BookDetailsViewController` or a `BookHistoryViewController` only when the appropriate property isn't nil.

```
class BookViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var detailsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var historyButton: UIButton!

    var book: Book!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        detailsButton.hidden = book.details == nil
        historyButton.hidden = book.history == nil
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        switch segue.identifier {
            case .Some("details"): prepareForDetailsSegue(segue)
            case .Some("history"): prepareForHistorySegue(segue)
            case let other: fatalError("unknown segue identifier \(other)")
        }
    }

    private func prepareForDetailsSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! BookDetailsViewController
        destination.details = book.details!
    }

    private func prepareForHistorySegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! BookHistoryViewController
        destination.history = book.history!
    }

}

class BookDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var details: Book.Details!

    // etc.

}

class BookHistoryViewController: UIViewController {

    var history: Book.History!

    // etc.

}
```

Comment: Thank you vm for your answer with the detailed code example. I think using nested classes are also a nice idea...